# create WSDL for specific SOAP request

Tags: soap, xsd, wsdl

I have to create a certain SOAP request message based on a WSDL file. I am using SOAP UI to create the SOAP request from the WSDL.

The SOAP request should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
SOAP-ENV:encodingstyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> 
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <username>xxxx</username>
    <password>xxxx</password>
    <MaxOrders>1</MaxOrders>
    <xmlVers>1</xmlVers>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <m:getNewOrders xmlns:m= "urn:https://xxx.yyy.co.uk/b2b/soap/soap:getNewOrders/">
    </m:getNewOrders>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have the following WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions 
xmlns:m="https://xxx.yyy.co.uk/b2b/" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
name="xxxOrders" 
targetNamespace="https://xxx.yyy.co.uk/b2b/">
 <wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="https://xxx.yyy.co.uk/b2b/">
  <xsd:element name="Envelope">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Header"/>
        <xsd:element name="Body"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="encodingstyle" type="xsd:anyURI" form="qualified" use="required" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="Header">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="username" type="xsd:NCName" form="unqualified" />
        <xsd:element name="password" type="xsd:integer" form="unqualified" />
        <xsd:element name="MaxOrders" type="xsd:integer" form="unqualified" />
        <xsd:element name="xmlVers" type="xsd:integer" form="unqualified" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="Body">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="m:getNewOrders" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="getNewOrders">
    <xsd:complexType />
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>

  <wsdl:message name="getNewOrders">
    <wsdl:part element="m:getNewOrders" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>


  <wsdl:portType name="xxxOrders">
    <wsdl:operation name="getNewOrders">
      <wsdl:input message="m:getNewOrders"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

  <wsdl:binding name="xxxOrdersSOAP" type="m:xxxOrders">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getNewOrders">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:https://xxx.yyy.co.uk/b2b/soap/soap:getNewOrders/"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>

  <wsdl:service name="xxxOrders">
    <wsdl:port binding="m:xxxOrdersSOAP" name="xxxOrdersSOAP">
      <soap:address location="https://xxx.yyy.co.uk/b2b/soap/soap_orders.asp"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
 </wsdl:definitions>
```

But when I take that WSDL and import it in SOAP UI, the SOAP request message looks different from what I expect:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:b2b="https://xxx.yyy.co.uk/b2b/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <b2b:getNewOrders/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My `Header` element is empty for example. The `getNewOrders` I think is okay because it is bound to `xmlns:b2b` so I do not need the namespace in the element getNewOrders. Am I correct?

Can please someone point out what I have to fix in the WSDL? I am lost.

Comment: Did you mean for `https://b2bqa.shoprite.co.za/b2b/` to be the same as `https://xxx.yyy.co.uk/b2b/`?

Comment: @John: thank you. yes, sorry about that - I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're ok with namespaces, the problem is that you didn't define the header part. Now, even if you do it, I wouldn't know if your tool will take into account... but definitely, in terms of interface definition this is what you must do.

Searching for "wsdl soap header example" or alike should yield many hits, such as [this one](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tipjax1.html).

The key points are:

- your input part should define the part that is related to the header.

> ```
>  <wsdl:message name="getNewOrders">
>      <wsdl:part element="m:getNewOrders" name="parameters"/>
>      <wsdl:part element="m:Header" name="header"/>
>  </wsdl:message>
> ```

- you need to bind that header part to the SOAP header

> ```
> <wsdl:operation name="getNewOrders">
>   <soap:operation soapAction="urn:https://xxx.yyy.co.uk/b2b/soap/soap:getNewOrders/"/>
>  <wsdl:input name="getNewOrders">
>    <wsdlsoap:header message="getNewOrders" part="header" use="literal"/>
>    <wsdlsoap:body use="literal" parts="parameters"/>
>  </wsdl:input>
>   <wsdl:output>
>     <soap:body use="literal"/>
>   </wsdl:output>
> </wsdl:operation>
> ```

Now, I haven't checked the prefixes (you should have a default namespace matching the targetNamespace of your WSDL for the above to work without prefixes, etc.) nor tried to rewrite the WSDL for you... but this is fundamentally how you specify the header: your input has multiple parts, which in SOAP one goes in the header, and the other in the body.

Comment: Thank you Petru Gardea, it works fine now. One strange thing is that apparently it matters to the webservice server if I use prefix "soapenv" or "SOAP-ENV". It only accepts "SOAP-ENV". But I will fix this with XSLT. Best regards, Peter

Comment: @Peter, that indeed is weird... as long as different prefixes are bound to the same namespace (URI), the choice of prefix (alias) should not matter to any decent XML parser that is namespace aware.

Comment: If the service cares which prefix is used, then it is badly broken. Your company should avoid doing business with other companies which cannot be bothered to follow simple industry standards which have been in place for over a decade.

Comment: @John: thank you for your helpful advice. I will definitely tell them about that. Another weird fact to me is that they want to change the password every 30 days. I think that is not necessary especially since also a certificate is used for server authentication. Their webservice I have to connect to is written Visual Basic. Best regards, Peter